# How do you isolate post-processing effects in Unity URP to specific objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, post-processing, urp

I am trying to apply a bloom effect to only certain things, specified by what layer they are on. I want all the things on a layer called "Bloom Layer" to have a bloom effect applied.

I thought that I could use Camera Stacking here, and have a 2nd camera with the volume on it, and then set the culling masks accordingly, applying the overlay bloom camera to the main camera stack. However this didn't work, and just makes everything glow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

My main camera:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p61Ao.png
The glow camera:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYEhm.png
The cubes as they are now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s2W7.png

Answer (score 0):

Unity URPs support local post processing volumes, https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@11.0/manual/Volumes.html

From you camera screenshots looks like you are using post processing package for default pipeline, instead of using post processing that is build in URP?

Comment: I am definitely using the URP post processing volumes. The Post Processing V2 package is uninstalled in my project, and the icons for that is the rainbow aperture looking symbol.

Local volumes I don't think is what I want either. That is where they only affect the camera, if the camera is within the bounds of a collider. I want a projectile which I shoot to glow regardless of where it is. 

I've asked in the Unity Developer Community discord too, and it just doesn't seem like something that is easily possible. :(

Comment: Hmm. You can try configure this with material emissions, put high threshold for bloom to trigger, and use HDR emission color on materials.

Answer (score 0):

In the GameObject where you have your volume (and therefore effects) add a differentiating layer (e.g. Post FX), then in the camera you want the post-processing effects to be rendered go to Environment>Volume Mask and select the layer you have just created. You can also exclude cameras from certain effects by using this.

Answer (score 0):

I was just strugling with this exact issue. As I understand it now and how it makes sense to me is that each camera is rendering on the top of the previous one and that post processing effects affect everything that was rendered before. That means if you render the scene first with no post processing and then you render the scene using your post process camera, the post processing on the second camera takes into account everything that was rendered before resulting in the glow being applied onto everything. Solution is to first render the post processing camera and then render the rest.

EDIT: Sorry it wont blend well with the environment rendered after. The non post processing rendering can override the glow effect...